# Tag badges to work for should be sorted with higher weight for the number of answers instead of score

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, tag-badges

Take a look at my list of tag badges I'm working for. Note this is the middle of my account on http://space.stackexchange.com

[image]

In order, it says I am closest to Rockets, then the-moon, and so on. It seems like the order is primarily determined by the votes, likely until the votes exceed 400, then it is determined by the answers. It seems like there is some method to take answers over score (Rockets is higher than the-moon, despite having a lower score)

My Proposal: I think this should actually be primarily answers, then points. Why? You can actively answer questions. You can't make people vote on your answers. Thus, producing new answers is something actionable, while getting people to vote on your answers isn't. It seems like there is a slight preference to votes, but it isn't absolute (the-moon has fewer answers, but more points, and is behind rockets), but it seems like it should be more weighted towards the number of answers produced. In these examples, I am much closer to having an acceptable score than have the number of answers. An average score of 5 points per answer is required to get the badge, with all 4 of these having well over 5 points per answer, the number of answers is really the limiting factor.

Another alternative is to select the lower of the two by percentage. That is the one that ultimately needs the work. I believe the current system is some sort of an average, perhaps weighted, between the two, a min would work better.

Comment: Is it not ordered by both? My tag badges here on MSE are seemingly not  primarily ordered by either score or answers.

Comment: There is a combination, but it weighs too much on the answer count, in my opinion.

Comment: I believe the sorting is implemented using the average of the (2%) rounded percentages. Both parts contribute equally.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Interesting... I would submit that the lower percentage is the more important one, however, and if that's the case, we should be basing it purely on the lower score.